# Look up a record with Fluid DatabaseQueryProcessor – without PID

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.x, typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 7.6, I would like to look up records from another (=any) page in a Fluidtemplate.

Based on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html, I tried `DatabaseQueryProcessor`:

```
  renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  renderObj {
    file = {$fluidPartialsPath}/Debug.html
    dataProcessing {
      20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
      20{
        # regular if syntax
        if.isTrue.field = records

        table = tt_content
        # quick&dirty to see the SQL table
        # where = stubrdebug

        # will pass these in programmatically later
        colPos = 1
        uidInList = 5
        # this doesn't work
        pidInList = *

        as = myrecords

        dataProcessing {
          10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
          10 {
            references.fieldName = image
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

The issue is that select always asks for a pid or add the one of the current page. So it behaves like a `CONTENT` Object.

How can I leave out the PID in the query?

All answers I could google point to simply using `RECORDS` – but I don't see how I could do that in `dataProcessing`. 
Is there a way?

PS on a larger scale: I would like to use fluid_styled_content's "Insert Records" Content Element to insert OTHER (=not from fsc), custom record types into the current page. I'm trying to build an own way to do that. Please tell me if that doesn't make sense and / or if there's an easier way than building everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `dataProcessing` only works on the current `$data` variable which needs to be filled in before, e.g. by a `CONTENT` object.

The `CONTENT` object uses the `select` function to get is data, therefore you have to use its `pidInList` property to configure the range of pages taken into account. Records without a page should live in the `root (pid=0)` and can be selected by the `root` keyword.

If you want to create a `Insert Records` functionality, then you should already have a list of `uid`from your records. Then you can simply use the `RECORDS` object to render the specific record, no matter on what page it is on.

Comment: I understand: I was using the wrong tool. I think I see how I'll have to build it now and will post what I have when I've got it